# CGAL "listen" edges modifications during insertion/removal of vertices

Tags: listener, triangulation, cgal

I'm using a `CGAL Delaunay triangulation` to index two dimensional objects.
I need to be notified about edges creations/deletions(/swaps) caused by insertions and removals of vertices.

Does `CGAL` provide any sort of `Listener` to this end?

If not, is there any workaround that wouldn't require modifying CGAL's source code?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that there is a Listener API.  But you can use the get_conflicts() method to find the faces that will disappear before you insert the point, from which you can easily deduct the edges.  And, once the insertion is done, the new edges are simply those incident to the new vertex.